# Is there a way to equalize the thickness of my grease pencil drawing over an entire scene? or per entire frame?

Tags: transforms, keyframes, grease-pencil

I drew and animated a whole scene using the grease pencil, but when moving from 2D animation tab to the 2D full canvas tab, it suddenly shows the difference in line thickness. Is there a way to equalize the thickness over the entire scene? or per entire frame? I tried to downscale using the object data tab and decreasing the ''stroke thickness'' and the "thickness scale", but that scales all the other lines with it as well leaving me with the same difference in thickness. I can scale using alt S, but I have a ton of frames. If I need to select only the thick lines in every frame and then alt S to the exact thickness the rest it's incovenient.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Thickness Modifier

Check my fast scribbled helper showing the might of the modifier.

[image: no joke]
Don't laugh, well you can, but only if this helped you, then i can laugh with you.
Joke aside, the modifier affects all layers under the same Stroke Object. It's slightly more work if you have multiple Stroke Objects. Then all need a modifier, but you can select all Stroke Objects and once you have "Normalize" active and the Thickness Factor set, just right click on each and use "Copy to selected" for each, that way all Stroke Objects or rather their Layers will be normalized and the same thickness.